# How to write a correct AND function?

Tags: excel, google-docs

I have two cells

```
MIN DATE: 2008-01-01 ($H10)
MAX DATE: 2012-02-01 ($H11)
```

I want to check if the value in $B16 is greater than MIN date AND less or equal to MAX DATE

This is what i write:

```
=AND($B16>$H10, $B16<=$H11)
```

the result is: parse error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which is it, Excel or Google Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the comma (",") with a semicolon (";").